# Convert text link to clickable link while pushing to CSV

Tags: python, dictionary, hyperlink, export-to-csv

The weblink obtained is text and not clickable. How to make the text url to clickable link before pushing to CSV in and while updating in dictionary.

Weblink is some text url like ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask which is not coming clickable in csv.

```
weblink = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
dict['url'] = weblink
```

This value is text but I want it as cickable link.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question, I don't think you can do this.  CSV is a text file.  If you want to export to Excel or something you might be able to format as a link, but csv is text only.

Comment: how to format as a link ??